# Setting ArrayField to null or []

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
files = fields.ArrayField(models.UUIDField(null=True), blank=True,
                              default=None)
```

So I have this line in my model, the task is to keep array of UUIDs of files in the field "files", but i still get an error

The array field was imported from postgres fields like so

```
from django.contrib.postgres import fields
```

and models was imported

```
from django.db import models
```

Here is the error while executing `python manage.py migrate` after `python manage.py makemigrations`

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 447, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "files" contains null values
```

Update: The thing is the field is should be optional, so if the client decides to upload a photo or any files related to this model later this should be done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want an array of non-nullable UUIDs:

```
files = fields.ArrayField(models.UUIDField(), blank=True)
```

That is, the array itself may not contain `null`s.

To initialize the field to an empty list, pass in a factory function (never a mutable object!); `list()`, as you know, returns an empty list.

```
files = fields.ArrayField(models.UUIDField(), blank=True, default=list)
```

If you do need to distinguish between NULL files and no files,

```
files = fields.ArrayField(models.UUIDField(), blank=True, null=True)
```

will do the trick.

(That said, are these `files` represented by other models? If so, you may really be looking for a `ManyToManyField`; this sort of array field has no referential integrity guarantees!)

Comment: Nope the thing is the array is only related and represented in this model, and won't be used in anything else. I've updated the question

Comment: Unless you need to distinguish between "the user has not chosen anything yet" (i.e. NULL or `None`) and "the user has chosen no files" (i.e. `[]`), this will work for the updated usecase.

Comment: Added another variation anyway.

Comment: Did you re-migrate? Are you sure you're not explicitly assigning `None` to the field if it's not `null=True`?

Comment: Fixed the problem by deleting prev migrations on the same field and then migrating again. Thanks for help!